# Shapefile failing to import using shp2pgsql?

Tags: shapefile, postgresql, shp2pgsql

I'm trying to import a shapefile (boundary.shp) using shp2pgsql. I'm using the following query

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 boundary ch01.test_boundary > psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d spatial_database -U postgres
```

After running the above import statement I get the following message:

```
Shapefile type: Polygon
Postgis type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
```

When I query for the table ch01.test_boundary it wasn't created, so it's failing.

I can successfully import the same shapefiles (get the same type messages, but the data is imported) using pgAdmin so I suspect it may have something to do with permissions.

I did notice i am not prompted for my password when running the above statement.

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 boundary ch01.test_boundary > psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d spatial_database -U postgres
```

You need to use the pipe `|` to redirect output from `shp2pgsql` into `psql`. You were using `>`, which will try to write the output of `shp2pgsql` to a file. Nothing will be piped into `psql`.

Comment: Also, you probably now have a file called "psql" in wherever you ran the command.

Comment: @til ha I feel silly now, that was it!